# mapbox leaflet setLayoutProperty

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to set the language of all labels to german.
So far I tried a few things but all resulted in a blank map.
I tried a few things including:

```
var language = "de";
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.places', {worldCopyJump: true})
        .setView([51.163375,10.447683], 6)
        .addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places', {
            autocomplete: true,
            keepOpen: true
        }));

    map.setLayoutProperty('country-label-lg', 'text-field', '{name_' + language + '}');
    map.setLayoutProperty('country-label-md', 'text-field', '{name_' + language + '}');
    map.setLayoutProperty('country-label-sm', 'text-field', '{name_' + language + '}');
```

and:

```
var language = "de";
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.places', {worldCopyJump: true})
        .setView([51.163375,10.447683], 6)
        .setLayoutProperty('country-label-lg', 'text-field', '{name_' + language + '}')
        .setLayoutProperty('country-label-md', 'text-field', '{name_' + language + '}')
        .setLayoutProperty('country-label-sm', 'text-field', '{name_' + language + '}')
        .addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places', {
            autocomplete: true,
            keepOpen: true
        }));
```

also customizing the style & layers but they all broke the map.

In the documentation for gl is an example
(https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/language-switch/) on how to change the language onclick with some buttons and I figured it couldn't be that different to my code.

```
document.getElementById('buttons').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var language = event.target.id.substr('button-'.length);
    // Use setLayoutProperty to set the value of a layout property in a style layer.
    // The three arguments are the id of the layer, the name of the layout property,
    // and the new property value.
    map.setLayoutProperty('country-label-lg', 'text-field', '{name_' + language + '}');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using mapbox-js not mapbox-gl-js. So you should use the correct documentation: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.1.1/ There you can see that the mapbox-js does not have a `setLayoutProperty` method like mapbox-gl-js. So what you are trying is never going to work.

Comment: Yeah, i figured as much. But i can't find any documentation to change the language in leaflet.

Comment: I am having a similar issue - users demand to have a map in their native language. Did you solve it?